# AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'add_widget'

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Iam a beginner and i wanted to make a to-do app with kivy
The problem is i can't add widget from screen to another

And that error  to me
AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'add_widget'
I don't know where is the problem
I need anyone to help me

There is the py part

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,ThreeLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton,MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    list11=ObjectProperty(None)
    
class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    field1=ObjectProperty(None)
    field2=ObjectProperty(None)
    field3=ObjectProperty(None)
    def but1(self):
        self.but2=MDRectangleFlatButton(text='remove')
        if self.field1.text=="":
            self.box=MDDialog(title='Your Username  ',text='you need to add Title',size_hint=(0.93,0))
            self.box.open()
        else:
            MenuScreen.list1.add_widget(ThreeLineListItem(text=self.field1,secondary_text=self.field2,tertiary_text=self.field3))



sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='profile'))

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen



DemoApp().run()
```

And this is the kv part

```
screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    list1:list1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'To-Dos'
            elevation: 8.6
        
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id:list1
        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                #mode: 'free-end'
                type: 'bottom'
                icon: 'plus'
                on_action_button:
                    root.manager.current = 'profile'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'profile'
    field1:field1
    field2:field2
    field3:field3
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:200
        spacing:'-50dp'
        MDLabel:
            text:'Add new To-Do:'
            font_size:'25dp'
            pos_hint: { "center_x":0.25}
        Widget:
        MDTextField:
            id:field1
            hint_text: "Title: "
            pos_hint: { "center_y":0.5, "center_x":0.49}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 1000
            size_hint_y: (None)
        
            helper_text:" Necessary"
            helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
        Widget:
        MDTextField:
            id:field2
            hint_text: "Description"
            pos_hint: { "center_y":0.5, "center_x":0.49}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 1000
            size_hint_y: (None)
        
            helper_text:" Important but optional"
            helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
        Widget:
        
    
        MDTextField:
            id:field3
            hint_text: "Time"
            pos_hint: { "center_y":0.5, "center_x":0.49}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 1000
            size_hint_y: (None)
        
            helper_text:" Optional"
            helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
        Widget:
        MDLabel:
            text:''
            font_size:'1dp'
  
  
        
        
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:'Add'
            pos_hint: { "center_x":1.05}
            on_release:
                root.but1()
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
                root.manager.current = 'menu'
            
        
        
   

    
  
  
        MDLabel:
            text:''
            font_size:'1dp'
        MDLabel:
            text:''
            font_size:'1dp'
        
        MDLabel:
            text:''
            font_size:'1dp'
"""
```

It is my first project

Thanks for help.

Comment: `MenuScreen.list1.add_widget` <- this is the mistake, you're accessing the class level ObjectProperty. You need to access the `list1` attribute of an _instance_ of the `MenuScreen` class, not the class itself.

Comment: Thanks,but can you write the correct code coz i didn't understand plz